# How to delete the space between QLabel and QLineEdit

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a QDialog window like this and I want to delete the space between 'Length', 'n', 'm' and corresponding QLineEdit input boxes. How can I achieve that ?

[image: demo]

Comment: Which layout you use inside left box? I recommend a simple formlayout.

Comment: @user3183610  I use QGridLayout

Comment: If you set the background color of the QLabels you will find out your QLabels are very large and pushing the QLineEdit to the right. Try setting the size of QLabels to something smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use gridlayout, I am not sure why your output looks like that. Generally Qt will not leave huge empty space like that, There are three possibility I can think of:

1. You have many SPACE after Length:, M: or N:
2. The layoutHorizontalSpacing is too large in your grid manager.
3. The layoutColumnStretch was set to in favor of label in your grid manager, should be "0,0", not "1,0". I mean, stretch of Label should not be higher than lineedit.

Still, I would use a simple form layout in your application.

Comment: I set QLineEdit to a fixed with of 30. Is that the reason ?

Comment: Yes, that can do it too. The reason being Qt allocate space top down, First the whole space, then set the QLineEdit to be 30 width, the rest space will be allocated to QLabel. You can try to resize your application to see the space between Qlabel and QLineEdit varies.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is reset the [alignment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#alignment-prop) of the labels:

```
    label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlighVCenter)
```

This can also be done in via the Property Editor in Qt Designer.

Comment: That partly solved the problem. The label and QLineEdit aligned to right. But this leaves a huge space in left. Is it possible to find a way to shrink the size of the Left QGridLayout after doing label.setAlignment ?

Comment: @Johnnylin. Yes, of course - just put an expanding horizontal spacer to the left of the frame. The frame will take up whatever space is available, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what to do with the space you want to remove :

- **Reduce the whole widget** : it depends on the surrounding layout, adding an horizontal layout on right or left of it will put the space out of your widget.
- **Space on the left of your labels** : you can align the label text to the right as *ekhumoro* suggested, or directly reduce and align to the right the whole frame by adding an horizontal spacer on its left (in the surrounding layout).
- **Space on the right of your line-edits** : like above you can add horizontal spacers or reduce and align the frame.
- **Expand the line-edits** : remove their fixed width (default horizontal policy is expanding) or set a bigger one.

The point is : the space has to be somewhere except if you reduce the parent widget or enlarge some the inner widgets. Size-policy is useful to tell which widget should take the available space, spacers are useful to let empty space between widgets.